# How to get JSON nested Array values with Node JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

I'm a Node.js newbie trying to parse the following JSON:

```
var data1 = {
         "_id":"R1::table::A1::order::167::comanda::2",
         "_rev":"1-ed6df32d3b4df9cc8019e38d655a86f5",
         "comanda":[
           [
             {
               "category":"Entradas",
               "itemName":"Ensalada de betabel",
               "modifierList":[
                 {
                   "modifierGroupName":"Modificadores de ensalada",
                   "modifierName":"Aderezo ranch",
                   "modifierPrice":10
                   },
                 {
                   "modifierGroupName":"Tamaños de Ensalada de betabel",
                   "modifierName":"Ensalada de betabel Grande",
                   "modifierPrice":100
                   }
                 ],
               "modifiersTotal":110,
               "price":0
               }
             ]
           ],
         "docType":"comanda",
         "operation":"N",
         "restaurantId":1,
         "userId":"admin"
       }
```

and I would like to get the values from `"itemName"` within `"comanda"` array and `"modifierName"` within `"modifierList"` array for further processing.

In order to get `"itemName"` I tried the following:

```
console.log('itemName:' + data1.comanda[0].itemName);
```

But I got this as result:

```
itemName: undefined
```

Any ideas on how to get these inner values? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You have two nested arrays there so it should be like this:

```
data1.comanda[0][0].itemName
```

The same for `modifierName`.

Comment: @javsonic Please always accept answers if you think they are good - so the question does not appear in 'Unanswered' section. Thanks.